# Show/Hide Button based on AD-group membership - C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

Trying and failing to Show/Hide my buttons based on group membership in Active Directory. Using the following code:

```
    private void AlterControlAppearance()
    {

        string username = System.Environment.UserName;

        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain");
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
        GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "myadgroup");

        if (user != null)
        {

            if (user.IsMemberOf(group))
            {
                button1.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                button1.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

If I move the code to private void InitializeComponent() (code under) it works perfectly, but that's just a solution to get it working while in debug. The form designer will stop working, since your not supposed to edit any Designer generated code.

```
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 22);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(208, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button1.Text = "MyButton";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        {

            string username = System.Environment.UserName;

            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain");
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
            GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "myadgroup");

            if (user != null)
            {

                if (user.IsMemberOf(group))
                {
                    button1.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    button1.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

What am I missing here? I have Googled around for hours without luck, might be my awful searching skills... Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: Call your `AlterControlAppearance()` method from the `Load()` event of the Form.

Comment: Thanks, @Idle_Mind ! Now I feel pretty stupid, but you learn something new every day.

Comment: No problem...and definitely don't feel stupid.  Every one has been there; have to start somewhere in our coding journey right?  On with learning!  March on...  =)